# Invalid syntax for turtle name (python)

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am trying to write a program to draw a flower, but no matter what I do it keeps throwing an "invalid syntax" error for the turtle name. I have taken out all of my other code, tried naming the turtle something different, yet nothing works. Any ideas?

```
import turtle

def draw_flower():
    window = turtle.Screen()
    window.bgcolor(#42dff4)

    sam = turtle.Turtle()
    sam.forward(50)

window.exitonclick()

draw_flower()
```

Comment: `window.bgcolor(#42dff4)` make the `#42dff4` a string. That is, wrap it in quotes.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: When you get a SyntaxError it's often a good idea to check the previous line. In your case, Python sees the `#` as starting a comment, and it can't tell that the syntax is bad until it sees the next line and realises that the `sam =` stuff is invalid after `window.bgcolor(`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides quoting the color string, as noted in the comments, your lines of code are in the wrong order.  For example, generally nothing should follow `window.exitonclick()`:

```
window.exitonclick()

draw_flower()
```

Make it (or `window.mainloop()`) the last statement of your program as that's when your code ends and the Tk event handler loop begins.  I.e. reverse the order of these two statements.  The second problem is that the variable `window` is in the wrong scope:

```
def draw_flower():
    window = turtle.Screen()
    ...

window.exitonclick()
```

Since it's defined locally in `draw_flower()`, it's not available to use globally.  Here's a rework of your code addressing both issues:

```
import turtle

def draw_flower():
    sam = turtle.Turtle()
    sam.forward(50)

window = turtle.Screen()
window.bgcolor("#42dff4")

draw_flower()

window.exitonclick()
```

Comment: Thank you so much!